# Showing a message in the terminal from which signal was sent

Tags: c++, linux, tty

My process in running as daemon. 
I want to reload the configuration using signal. 
The problem is that if configuration is wrong it should error message in the tty form which signal was sent.

1. Is there a way to do this?
2. Is it recommended way?

If it is not recommended way. What will be a more appropriate way to check if it was successful or not?

Comment: I think a more solid approach would be write a "remote control" program for your wrapper that people can use to do things like restart, reload config etc. Something like "apachectl" for the Apache web server.

Answer (score 6):

For getting pid of signal source, you need to use `sa_sigaction` instead of `sa_handler` when you set signal handlers:

```
static pid_t g_killer_pid = 0;

static void signal_handler( int num, siginfo_t *info, void* blabla )
{
    g_killer_pid = info->si_pid;
}

int main(void)
{    
    struct sigaction sa;

    memset( &sa, 0, sizeof(sa) );
    sa.sa_sigaction = &signal_handler;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction( SIGTERM, &sa, NULL );
    sigaction( SIGINT,  &sa, NULL );

    pause();
    hello_killer( g_killer_pid );

    return 0;
}
```

Now you have pid of the source process.

For getting terminal id of the source process is not so simple. 
One way is read it from `proc/<pid>/stat` file. One number in the file is `tty_nr`. 
`tty_nr` is little bit strange for me, so I don't know is this even portable stuff.
But it holds minor number, that can be used for opening correct terminal for writing:

```
static void hello_killer( pid_t killer )
{
    char filename[200];
    FILE* fil;
    FILE* out;
    int tty_nr;

    sprintf( filename, "/proc/%ld/stat", (long int)killer );
    fil = fopen( filename, "r" );
    if( fil )
    {
        if( fscanf( fil, "%*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %d ", &tty_nr ) == 1 )
        {
            sprintf( filename, "/dev/pts/%d", (tty_nr & 0xF) | ((tty_nr >> 20) & 0xFFF) );

            out = fopen( filename, "a" );
            if( out )
            {
                fprintf( out, "Hello!\n" );
                fclose( out );
            }
        }
        fclose( fil );
    }
}
```

I am not sure is that `/dev/pts` trick correct/best way to do it. But it seems to work in my Linux box:

```
~ # killall temp_test
Hello!
~ #
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you something like catching `SIGUSR1` and then reload the configuration?

You should remember that signal handlers should be as small and quick as possible, and not do something that can cause another signal. So basically you should refrain from I/O as much as possible. What is probably the best way to do this is to have a very simple signal handler that only sets a flag, then in your main loop you check for this flag and then reload your configuration in the context of your main thread. There you can output to the console all you want.

Comment: What should be idle sleep time in that loope check ?

Comment: @VivekGoel That is totally up to you. If your program is event-driven then you can use something that fits into the event framework you are using instead of flags (e.g. condition variables, pipes).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but there's no trivial way to do it. You need to arrange a mechanism for the  daemon to feedback to the process sending the signal.

Some possible ways of doing that include:

- Write the (timestamped) result to a file in a predetermined location.
- Have the daemon maintain a shared memory segment with the information in a known structure.
- Have the daemon listen on a named pipe/socket of some sort and give out feedback that way. (You could also send the reload command via that channel).
- Have the thing that sends the signal and the daemon link against a shared library so that both are capable of validating the configuration file. Validate the file before raising the signal.

Of those a named pipe would be my first choice I think - you can restrict access to it with normal permissions and it's the easiest to make robust and correct.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt, that you can determine the source of the signal and even, if you could so, it don't have to be a terminal. What about using a simple tcp/ip protocol? Accept tcp/ip connections on a special port. Read a command until a first new line. If that command is "reconfigure", do the reconfiguration and send a message over the established TCP/IP connection.